# Calling Clojure Functions Loaded from File

Tags: clojure

I am working on a clojure DSL for guitar tablature and I want to allow users to write plugins by defining a function called `apply-clojure-plugin` in a known file location (say `plugins.clj`).

I've tried:

- `load` the file and calling the function (resulting in "Unable to find symbol: apply-clojure-function".
- Adding a `declare` to avoid the above issue (resulting in "Attempting to call unbound fn")

I'm guessing it is some sort of namespace issue but I can't quite make out how to use `ns-resolve` here (if it's even necessary).

EDIT: I ended up solving this with `resolve`.  The issue was that `apply-clojure-plugin` isn't defined at compile time (since it is defined in the file), so an error is thrown during compilation.  Calling `(resolve 'apply-clojure-plugin)` works fine.

Comment: You don't need `ns-resolve`. `ns-resolve` is for looking up a symbol based on the mappings of another ns, where for your purposes all you need is to make a mapping to the other ns - you don't need the thing the other ns sees, just the things it defines.

Answer (score 2):

You either want `(load "plugins")` (if the directory containing the file is on the classpath), or `(load-file "path/to/plugins.clj")` to load from a known file path relative to the execution (or absolute path).

If the file contains no `ns` form, you will be able to access its definitions directly. Otherwise, you will need to know which ns the file defines, and you can use `alias` to map that namespace into your own:

```
;; make a new namespace for demonstration purposes
:user=> (ns foo)
nil
;; a definition in the other namespace
:foo=> (def bar "hello")
#'foo/bar
;; switch back to the original namespace
:foo=> (in-ns 'user)
#object[clojure.lang.Namespace 0x14a50707 "user"]
;; our definition is not visible
:user=> (resolve 'bar)
nil
;; but it is visible based on the fully qualified namespace
+user=> (resolve 'foo/bar)
#'foo/bar
;; using alias, we can make a convenient shorthand
+user=> (alias 'f 'foo)
nil
+user=> f/bar
"hello"
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me in either case.  With an `(ns plugins)` declaration in the file, if I call `load-file` and then the fully-qualified function I get: `No such namespace: plugins`.  Without the `ns` I get `Unable to resolve symbol: apply-clojure-plugin in this context`

Comment: what does `(apropos "plugin")` return?

Comment: `(apropos "plugin")` returns `(plugins/apply-clojure-plugin)`, but when I add a call to `plugins/apply-clojure-plugin` I still get `No such namespace: plugins`.  It appears that the error is happening at compile time, which would make sense since the `plugins` namespace isn't created until the file is run.

Comment: right, this is why you use resolve, as in my examples